# Объект со значением Null в параметрах методов TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Я изучаю Angular по учебному проекту. У меня стоит 11 версия, в учебнике используется 9. В учебнике определяется переменная:

```
selectedBook: BookModel = null;
```

значение null используется для отображения всего списк.
У меня так не пропускала IDE? поэтому я исправил на такой вариант:

```
selectedBook: BookModel | null = null;
```

Вот только это исправление потянуло за собой правку всех методов и кода внутри методов:

```
selectBook(book: BookModel | null): void {
    bookServis.add(book) - тут тоже ругается, что тип не null
```

bookServis это интерфейс

```
add(t: T): Observable<T> {
  ...
}
```

и когда я в html файле присваиваю переменную selectedBook объекту BookModel

```
[selectedBook]="selectedBook"
```

тоже ругается, что BookModel не может быть null

т.е. теперь везде, где используется переменная selectedBook приходится указывать, что в тип объекта может быть еще и null.
Как то можно от этого наследия избавиться? А то не очень красиво получается, вроде как это null только при старте приложения задействован, а приходится везде его учитывать.
Может можно это как-то переделать, но я чет не представляю как, в обычных языках null для объекта ни каких проблем не вызывает, а тут с этим проблема.

Comment: достаточно один раз проверить на null перед передачей параметра

Answer (score 1):

Если книга адекватная, то возможно, её код рассчитан на выключенный `strictNullChecks` в конфиге тайпскрипта. Впрочем, его рекомендуется включать.

Если это какой-то одиночный косяк, то можно обмануть тайпскрипт так:

```
selectedBook: BookModel = null!;
```

Если поле присваивается в конструкторе, то присваивание вообще писать не надо:

```
selectedBook: BookModel;
```

Если поле присваивается в конструкторе, но не непосредственно в нём, а в каком-то другом методе, из-за чего тайпскрипт этого не видит, то можно объявить так:

```
selectedBook!: BookModel;
```

Comment: В том проекте нет этого свойства strictNullChecks в настройках. Только там используется Angular 9 и TypeScript 3.8.

Comment: Раз работает, значит есть.